# Style WebView Inline HTML in React Native

Tags: react-native, webview

I need to render some HTML text inside my application, I just tried using [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) which is working as expected, but I still need to add some specific styling say `lineHeight`, `fontSize` and `fontFamily` though it seems it does not allow me to apply these styles.

I need to do this to make sure content is consistent with the rest of my application, here's a picture for reference.

[image: Web View]

Here's how the code looks:

```
<View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
  <WebView
    source={{ html: canjeableDetail?.description }}
    style={{
      marginTop: 6,
      marginLeft: 16,
      marginRight: 16,
    }}
  />
</View>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by using the [InjectJavaScript](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-injectedjavascript-prop) which then allowed me to apply some basic styling, though I had to make a few changes.

```
// Inject JS for styling
// Original Styling
// lineHeight: 20,
// fontFamily: "Montserrat",
// fontSize: responsiveFontSize(1.6),
const docStyle = `
  document.body.style.fontSize = ${responsiveFontSize(4)};
  document.body.style.lineHeight = 1.7;
  document.body.style.fontFamily = "Montserrat";
  `;

<View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
  <WebView
    source={{ html: canjeableDetail?.description }}
    style={{
      marginTop: 6,
      marginLeft: 16,
      marginRight: 16,
    }}
    injectedJavaScript={docStyle}
  />
</View>;
```